# Si je peux me permettre faute ou pas ?

Tags: conjugaison

C'est juste pour savoir, il me semblait que *« si je peux me permettre »* était une faute mais je n'ai rien trouvé à ce sujet.

Donc doit-on dire :

> Si je puis me permettre

Ou peut-on dire :

> Si je peux me permettre ?

Comment: Votre question est très difficile à comprendre, il vaudrait peut-être mieux un peu structurer avec des ""